# Outstanding charges Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have a big problem. I am a student and i had a project to do for school, and i had to use google maps api. I needed to use a sql database to stock the data, and i tried to use the google cloud sql, but i ended up not using it. I thought it is all included in a free trial, and i forgot about it an now google tries to charge me with 388$, and i cannot pay those money.
I work and i have a salary, but i will be left with not enough money until next month, and i don't know how to get support from google.
Anyone has an idea how can i resolve this?

Comment: I tried this tactic last time I put gas in my car, needless to say, it didn't fly.

Comment: I know it is my mistake, but it do not feels right to pay for something i did not used, and because it was misleading for me.

Comment: You can contact [here](https://cloud.google.com/contact) Call the Google Cloud sales team at: 844-613-7589 | Representatives are available Monday—Friday, 8:00 AM - 8:00 PM EST

Comment: Hi, thanks, i manage to get in contact with a google agent and they started a process to help me with this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i managed to speak with a billing agent and he helped to get one-time courtesy adjustment, and now I am free of my bill.